# How to wait the result of async operations without await?

Tags: c#, async-await

```
void A()
{
    foreach (var document in documents)
    {
       var res = records.BulkWriteAsync(operationList, writeOptions); // res is Task<BulkWriteResult<JobInfoRecord>>
    }
}
```

After `foreach` I would like to wait the result of all `BulkWriteAsync`, how to do this? I don't want to mark `A()` as `async` and do the following

`await records.BulkWriteAsync(operationList, writeOptions);`

Is it good solution?

```
void A()
{
var tasks = new List<Task<BulkWriteResult<JobInfoRecord>>>();

foreach (var document in documents)
{
     var task = records.BulkWriteAsync(operationList, writeOptions);
     tasks.Add(task);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

I call `A()` in `try catch` if I will mark `public async void A()` as `async` I never be in `catch`

Comment: Try `Task.Wait(records.BulkWriteAsync(operationList, writeOptions));`

Comment: So you only want to wait for the result of the last operation or what? And why don't you want to make `A` `async`? Asynchronous call chains should really be asynchronous as far as they can go.

Comment: Next time you should clearly express what you want to achieve in the question. That is why it's always a good idea to post a [MCVE].

Comment: @Luaan I don't want to leave the method `A()` until all `BulkWriteAsync` are not will end (will finished)

Comment: Do you want to wait until the end of foreach, or you need to wait each BulkWrite?What is operationList? What is document?

Comment: You still didn't say why making the method `async` isn't an option for you. It should really be the default when dealing with asynchronous code.

Comment: That just means that at some point, you break the `await` chain without handling the orphaned `Task` properly. Why do you do that? Are you using `async void` methods? Don't. If you don't need to return any data, just use `async Task` instead.

Comment: @Luaan Can you show me please, in your answer, how to use `async-await` and don't leave `A()` until  `BulkWriteAsync` finished?

Comment: I've added some more information.

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko: I have written an entire [article on this subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). `WaitAll` and friends are some of the worst approaches.

Comment: @StephenCleary If `WaitAll` is worst approache. What would you recommend, if I cannot use `async-await`?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko: Read [my article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). But first, think *really hard* about whether you can actually use `await` or not. Most of the time people say they "can't", it's actually that they *can* but they don't *want* to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first you want a `Task` that represents all the operations. The simplest way to do this is with a bit of LINQ:

```
Task.WhenAll(documents.Select(i => records.BulkWriteAsync(...)));
```

Then, you ideally want to `await` that task. If that isn't possible, you can try

```
task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

However, make sure that none of the tasks have thread affinity - that's a great way to get a deadlock. Waiting for a task on the UI thread while the task itself needs the UI thread is a typical example.

The whole point of `await` is that it allows you to handle asynchronous code as if it were synchronous. So from the outside, it appears as if you never left the method until you actually get to a `return` (or the end of the method). For this to work, however, your method must return a `Task` (or `Task<T>`), and the callee must `await` your method in turn.

So a code like this:

```
try
{
  tasks = Task.WhenAll(documents.Select(i => ...));

  await tasks;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Handle the exception
}
```

will appear to run completely synchronously, and all exceptions will be handled as usual (though since we're using `Task.WhenAll`, some will be wrapped in `AggregateException`).

However, this isn't actually possible to handle with the way .NET and C# is built, so the C# compiler cheats - `await` is basically a `return` that gives you a promise of the result you'll get in the future. And when that happens, the control returns back to where the `await` left the last time. `Task` is that promise - if you use `async void`, there's no way for the callee to know what's happening, and it has no option but to continue as if the asynchronous method was a run-and-forget method. If you use `async Task`, you can `await` the async method and everything "feels" synchronous again. Don't break the chain, and the illusion is perfect :)

Comment: It is never really wise to call `Result`, `Wait` or `GetResult`. If you need it, your design is wrong.

Comment: @Gusdor Sometimes it's not your choice. Maybe you're called by a framework that doesn't support asynchronous methods. A synchronous wait works, as long as you make sure to avoid synchronization issues (as with any multi-threaded code). It's not desirable, of course, but sometimes you just don't have a choice.

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko If you can't use `await`, it's passable. However, `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will give you a lot more meaningful stack traces - it pretends as if everything was a synchronous chain of method calls, pretty much. `Wait` doesn't lie, so you might get the same stack trace as with `GetResult`, but it might also give you no useable stack trace at all.